# Where does (no domain) > extensions::name come from?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

On the sources tab in DevTools, some pages have a (no domain) folder with various extensions inside of them. The source seems to indicate that they are chrome extensions, but I can't find any information about them. For example, this page listed many extensions including extensions::unload_event, extensions::messaging, extensions::Event, extensions::last_error, etc.

What are they? Who made them? Is this something Chrome is doing, or is it something front-end developers are responsible for including? Is there any documentation about these particular extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These `extensions::[name]` files are part of the extension platform's implementation, and bundled with Chrome. Extension developers don't need to know about their existence.

You can view their source at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/extensions/renderer/resources.